# What's the meaning of "thread"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this word in [Github guide](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#notifications), and I don't know how to translate it to Chinese.It is used in this context:

> Muted **threads** won’t show up as unread again until you are specifically @mentioned again. This makes muting a great strategy for **threads** that you have little interest in (perhaps a sub-system that you aren’t familiar with). If you mark an issue as read, it will stay that way until someone comments on the **thread** again.

Comment: You could try [chinese.se] for a Chinese translation.

Comment: Note that "thread" is being used as a bit of technical jargon, and it's meaning will differ (at least to a minor degree) between technical arenas.  What one discipline calls a "thread" another may call a "process", eg.  But in the above sense, a "Question" here and all of its associated "Answers" and "Comments" is a "thread".

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey does [chinese.se] accept translation requests? Most language sites don't. Please don't suggest other SE sites unless you *know* that a question would be welcome there. I just checked and they seem to have a rather strict translation request [policy](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @terdon *Can I request a translation?*

*We are happy to assist with your translation questions if you are having a specific problem. **Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with.***

*Open-ended questions regarding the accuracy of a translation or asking for a translation of a word or passage without showing previous effort are not allowed.*  On-topic as long as some prior attempt at translation is shown.

Comment: Yes, precisely: **asking for a translation of a word or passage without showing previous effort are not allowed.** Anyway, my main point is to please only suggest other sites if you are familiar enough with their scope to know how a question would be received there. Unfortunately, user often suggest other sites without actually knowing what those sites' scope is and that causes grief for everyone involved.

Answer (score 4):

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thread

> 7. *(Internet)* A series of messages, generally grouped by subject, in which all messages except the first are replies to previous messages in the thread.

Comment: @ChaoyangLiu If this answers your question, you can mark this answer as accepted.